# it's possible to add a jar library to a Flutter project (dart)?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, jar

I have an existing Android project that using a jar library, this project i will re developpe it using Flutter (dart), but my issue is that i didn't find a way to add this .jar library, also for .so files, it's possible to do that in Flutter project ?

Comment: You can add a jar to your android subproject. Then you can use [platform channels](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-kotlin-tab#example) to communicate between your dart code and your subproject code.

Comment: thanks for your reply, what about the .so files ? it's the same as the .jar files?

Comment: Yes, you can add whatever files you want to your android subproject the same way you would any other android project.

Comment: thanks again i try it and it's work using platform channels ! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @mmcdon20 said in his comment, using the [platform channels](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-kotlin-tab#example) helps me to communicate between dart code and my android code (kotlin)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.